# Float rounding in python 2.6 on 32-bit platform

Tags: python, rounding

I am using quite old Python 2.6.6 on Debian 6 (32-bit). Faced issue that any number with decimal 1 after dot represented like: `37.100000000000001` instead of `37.1`. Ok, I'd like to return it as in was introduced, i.e. `37.1` as float in JSON response. And I want in returned as float (otherwise `'{0}'.format(number)` saves me).

UPD: sample taked on my system:

```
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Dec 27 2010, 00:02:40)
[GCC 4.4.5] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> f = 37.1
>>> f
37.100000000000001
>>> round(f,2)
37.100000000000001
```

When JSON prepared it looks like:

```
>>> import json
>>> f = 37.1
>>> json.dumps({'value': f})
{ 'value': 37.100000000000001 }
```

But I want it be:

```
{ 'value': 37.1 }
```

Comment: What? Are you talking about the result of `json.dumps`? Or something else? Could you give a [mcve]?

Comment: 1/10th can never be exactly represented in a floating point number, regardless of the bit-size.

Comment: @jonrsharpe updated post with required code sample

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes, I know. Question as how to send it to resulting JSON with desired form.

Comment: So what are you trying to use that number for? Why is its `repr` particularly important? If you want to *"send it to resulting JSON"*, why aren't you using `json`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Hope it is more understandable with last update

Comment: Perhaps `round(f*100) / 100.0` could help as a workaround.

Comment: @MC93 well, not really, the problem is (in short) that you can't represent all of the infinite real numbers with a finite number of bits, so some are necessarily approximations. This is just the abstraction leaking.

Comment: @AlexG.P.: JSON float numbers are still float numbers, it doesn't matter one bit if you include more precision in the string representation of the number.

Comment: @MartijnPieters it is not my wish to manually handle 1/10th, but I cannot explain it to customer who is argued that he passed 37.1 and he want it returns back.